# Replacement in regular expression

Tags: regex, replace, preg-replace, expression, regular-language

I have a list:

```
1  name1
2  name2
3  name3
```

I need to replace all 1,2,3... to '1', '2', '3'...and name1, name2, name3 to 'name1', 'name', 'name'3.
I know how to do it via '\n' and '\s'.

But I think the better way exists. Does anybody know this way?

Comment: I hope you mean `to 'name1', 'name2', 'name3'`, otherwise the logic eludes me...

Comment: So the main aim is to convert this list to array.
array('1' => 'name1', '2' => 'name2', '3' => 'name3').
I would like to do it _only_ via netbeans or other editor where I can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a little snippet in PHP:

```
$str = "1 name1\n2 name2\n3 name3";
$str2 = preg_replace('!([^\s]+)\s([^\n]+)!sm', "'$1' '$2'", $str);
echo $str2;
```

It uses $1 and $2 to reference the rounded bracket you 'catched' in the string

Comment: Sorry, but you are using some languages here. 
It doesn't work if you have editor only without js and php etc.
Of course I can create php or js script and do replacement then.

At the same time it is interesting to do this in editor only.

Comment: you didn't mention you want to do this in an editor. try this (or the JS one which is simpler) in the editor's find&replace. if its based on PCRE, it should work..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JavaScript solution:

```
str = str.replace(/(\w+)/g, "'$1'");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it easily with perl,

on a unix machine, from the terminal:

```
perl -pe 's/regex/replace/' input > output
```

(the > output is optional, and it will just get printed to the terminal)

so:

```
perl -pe "s/([0-9]+)\s(.*)/'\1' '\2'/g" file > file2
```

That will find at least one number at the beginning, and capture it (as **\1**). then some white space, then the rest of the line, captured (as **\2**). the after the **/** is the replace bit. just add in the **'** s and insert the captured bits.

(if you're on windows, you can get perl here: http://www.perl.org/get.html#more)